# How to test the number of constructor parameters in Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Let's say I have a very simple class defined in `MyClass.ts`

```js
export class MyClass {
  private foo:string;
  private bar:number;

  constructor(foo:string, bar:number){
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}
```

How can I write a test which will check that the `MyClass` constructor has the correct number of parameters (and idealy their type as well)?

i.e. if someone defines `MyClass` as any one of the following, I want the test to fail:

```js
export class MyClass {
  constructor(foo:string){}
}
```

```js
export class MyClass {
  constructor(foo:string, bar:number, a:string){}
}
```

```js
export class MyClass {
  constructor(bar:number, foo:string){}
}
```

```js
export class MyClass {
  constructor(a:any, b:any){}
}
```

Comment: Number of parameters is pretty easy (but unstable and buggy); this is JavaScript, so we can stringify the constructor and get the params from there with regex :p

Comment: @caTS how do you stringify the *class* or the constructor? I mean, `JSON.stringify(MyClass.constructor)` gives `undefined`

Comment: Ah wait... I'm being silly... this is already available to you as `length`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a class:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(foo:string, bar:number, a:string) {}
}
```

You can already get how many (named) parameters the constructor expects:

```
console.log(MyClass.length);
```

So you could just test if this `length` is equal to 3, for example.

Comment: Oh cool, I was doing `MyClass.constructor.length` which doesn't work. So I can get the number of parameters at least. I guess I need to figure out some way to trying to check the type as there isn't any native support for that.